# Membership.Islockedout property not available

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using aspnet_Membership in my asp.net MVC 3 application and I am using  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" in web.config under membership\providers. I see that user is lockedout after 5 attempts ( that is what I want). Now on login view I want to show user that you are lockedout due to 5 invalid attempts. But I dont see provider.Islockedout property there.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code to check if the user is locked out.

```
   MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser(userName); 
   if (usr.IsLockedOut)
       // do whatever action...
```

Comment: Thanks @vijay. that worked. and when it unlocks automatically. I see that account is locked out and I cant login with correct password even. Do I need to manually unlock or it will do after some time?

Comment: You must unlock the user manually to relogin.  You can also do this programmatically too if needed